# A Matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $n \times n$ full-rank matrices.

Let $XAY = B$ be the given equation where $X$ and $Y$ are unknown $n \times n$ matrices. We know that $Vec(B) = (Y^{T} \otimes X)Vec(A)$. Under what conditions can we determine $X$ and $Y$ and what would be the procedure to determine $X$ and $Y$?

Not looking for the obvious solutions such as $Y^{-1}=A$ and $X=B$, $A$ is the eigenvalue (or some multiple of eigenvalue) diagonal matrix of $B$ where $X$ and $Y$ diagonalizes $B$ and $A$ and $B$ are similar to $X$ and $Y$. In general are there any other possible choices that $Y^{T} \otimes X$ can take? These may be the only choices for general $A$ and $B$. However, given $A$ and $B$ are some other structured matrices, has such an equation been studied before?

Comment: $X=I$ and $Y=A^{-1}B$? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Since $A$ and $B$ are invertible, replace $X$ by $X' = XA$ and replace $Y$ by $Y' = YB^{-1}$.  Then your equation reduces to solving $X'Y' = I$, i.e. the space of solutions is parametrized by $GL(n)$.

Comment: I was actually curious of a meaning behind Theorem 9.3.5 here: http://books.google.com/books?id=vVTdbb6930EC&pg=PA304&lpg=PA304&dq=ryser+1973+%22formal+intersection+matrix%22&source=bl&ots=4UdlbmOQtY&sig=WK-P7yfkdW8oD1pdQ6-JI3MLZZw&hl=en&ei=jrRdTuuMLPO50AG9uJmDAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=ryser%201973%20%22formal%20intersection%20matrix%22&f=false

Comment: No idea about that, sorry.  I can't see the second half of the theorem since Google is not showing me page 311.

Comment: I think you need only pages 309 and 310!